# How to stop loading chunks from different pages in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, webpack-splitchunks

I am trying to improve the lighthouse performance of my nextjs project but I keep on seeing unwanted js being loaded in the webpage. The following image is a screenshot of the coverage [image]

Some chunks of different pages are also being loaded. What can I do to stop the loading of unwanted chunks ? I have explored splitchunkspluggin , removed many unwanted package,used dynamic imports but nothing seems to work. Currently Nextjs v12 and React v17 is being used.
I have done a lot of optimizations on this project but nothing seems to bring any significant change in the project.
This was the earlier build report[image]
but after making some changes the current build report is this

[image]

I have tried almost everything I found on the internet like upgrading the nextjs version , making some changes to the splitchunk plugin that is manually splitting some of the chunks , adding prefetch={false} to the  component , tried to use dynamic imports from next/dynamic but nothing seems to make any improvements to the performance.

This is the current lighthouse report[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `<Link>` component from next.js, you should set the `prefetch` props to `false` to tell next to not automatically prefetch linked pages.

I bet you would still want a prefetch to happen for UX reasons, you can do that manually in a useEffect after the page has loaded so as not to affect initial loading with next router `router.prefetch([path])`

Comment: I applied prefetch={false} to every <Link> tag I could find but still haven't seen any appreciable improvements in the website. What should I do now ?

Comment: How do u measure `improvements` ? What is your goal ?

Comment: I measure the improvements through lighthouse score or webpagetest.org . Currently the scores I am getting is very poor. Basically it is just a website of my company and I want to improve it's performance for the mobile users

Comment: do you test lighthouse score using the built version or while in dev?